# Force to include the Default value Attribute property in the SOAP Request from NET Web Service Proxy class

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have added web service reference to the public domain web service.

While making call to one of the Web Service API, it expects the value for all the properties of the object. But it is observed that in case property has following attribute 'DefaultValue'. It is not included in the SOAP request at all.

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute(false)]
    public bool replaceAll {
        get {
            return this.replaceAllField;
        }
        set {
            this.replaceAllField = value;
        }
    }
```

Somehow this is creating problem and failing the web service call. Is there any web service proxy option to force .NET Proxy class to include this property in the SOAP Request

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when sending SOAP request to the service, and then I realized that there is another boolean that should be specified in order to include it to request: property name + "Specified".

In your case it is replaceAllSpecified. This should be set to true!